# $X \sim U[a,b]$. Find $c$ and $d$ so that $Y = c + dX$ is $U[0,1]$

Tags: probability

Suppose $X \sim U[a,b]$. Find $c$ and $d$ so that $Y = c + dX$ is $U[0,1]$.

Here is what I have tried to do

$P(Y \leq y) = P(c + dX \leq y) = P(X \leq \frac{y-c}{d})$.

Now I know $X \sim U[a,b]$ but I am not sure how to use this fact to get what I want to show. And hence I am stuck.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

(we have $d>0$)

$$0\le c+dX\le1\Rightarrow -c\le dX\le1-c\Rightarrow \frac{-c}{d} \le X\le\frac{1-c}{d}$$
Hence, $$\frac{-c}{d} =a,\,\frac{1-c}{d}=b$$
Solve for $c$ and $d$ to get

$$c=\frac{-a}{b-a},\, d=\frac{1}{b-a}$$

Comment: That explains it. Thanks.